Conversion to Japanese onyomi
I recently started learning Japanese, and noticed that one may find some pronunciation similarities between mandarin, onyomi Japanese, and Korean.
Here are a few examples:

教室:きょうしつ:교실
秘密:ひみつ:비밀

Is there any sort of set of rules to follow in order to convert the pronunciation in one language to another? That would be pretty useful to easily and quickly expand my Japanese vocabulary as I have several thousand words of vocabulary in Chinese and Korean that could potentially be reused.

教室:きょうしつ:교실
秘密:ひみつ:비밀 Your example have already shown rule. つーㄹ. and There are another rules.

You can read these articles:

Sino-Xenic vocabularies (mostly this section)

Sino-Korean vocabulary (mostly this section)

Sino-Japanese vocabulary (mostly this section)


However this knowledge would only allow to predict group of more likely phonemes (e.g. Sino-Korean syllable-initial /t/ usually corresponds to Sino-Japanese /t/ OR /d/), and is not replacement for actually learning correct pronunciation.

Sorry. there are no rules.
You know, same kanji(hanza, hanzi) means they have same origin.
that's over. A long time has passed, and there are no laws to the changes that have occurred to them.
Consider how differently words with the same Latin origin are read in English and other languages.

Go deeper, there are cases where the same Chinese characters are used but their meanings are different.
Case 華奢)
in korea : gorgeous
in japanese : thin, cute, slender
I'm Korean, and it took me 10 years to understand the phrase "華奢な車" in Japanese. This is an expression used by a Japanese journalist to describe a thin car like the Lotus 7 with a visible chassis.

What's a little more distressing is that words referring to the same place are different in common language usage. The box office is where you buy your tickets. In Korea, it is 매표소(賣票所,mapyoso). In Japan it is チケット売り場(ticketouriba).
